# Are questions about programming language design on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently proposed an idea for a new Stackexchange site over on Area51 [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88831/programming-language-creation), and it was almost immediately closed as a duplicate of this site. Is that correct? Is programming language design on-topic here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, programming language design is one of the things computer scientists do. You'll find programming language design questions under tags such as [programming-languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages), [typing](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typing), [type-checking](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-checking), [type-inference](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-inference), [compilers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compilers), [interpreters](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreters), etc. as well as under tags for specific programming paradigms such as [constraint-programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constraint-programming), [functional-programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming), [meta-programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-programming), etc.

Comment: There's also [tag:language-design].

Answer (score 7):

Programming language design is on topic, though some people are rather keen on suggesting that anything related to programming should be closed.

I, for one, welcome more programming languages questions.

Comment: I think "programming" and "design of programming languages" are sufficiently distinct disciplines so that saying "programming questions are offtopic" does not imply that questions about PL design are offtopic as well.

Comment: @Raphael We have a problem sometimes with semantics questions that contain code getting votes to close, though it's usually questions about the semantics of an existing language rather than the design of a new one that are problematic.